# What happens if no SD Card is in?

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I asked myself today what happens, if I try to save something to the SD card in my app programmatically and no SD card is in or the device doesn't provide a SD card. Does the app crash or what will it do?

Comment: It will generate an exception, and of course it will crash if you don't handle it

Comment: Did the answer helped you???